# Generation of random numbers and the use of random.seed()

Tags: python, random, http-post

I have a script, which should generate a random number, which represents a sensor temperature between 25 and 28°C inclusive, and perform a POST request with some xml in the body. The code is structured like this:

```
def randomTemperature():
    random.seed()
    return str(random.randint(25,28))

create_DATA_contentInstance_xml_body = '''<obj>
                                         <str name="appId" val="''' +        new_senzor_name + '''"/>
                                         <str name="category" val="temperature "/>
                                         <int name="data" val="''' + randomTemperature() + '''"/>
                                         <int name="unit" val="celsius"/>
                                    </obj>'''

create_DATA_contentInstance = urllib2.Request(url=create_DATA_contentInstance_url , 
                                  data=create_DATA_contentInstance_xml_body, 
                                  headers={'Authorization': 'Basic abcaW46YabcaW4='})   

def createDATAcontentInstance():
    urllib2.urlopen(create_DATA_contentInstance)                
    print "\n=== Created a DATA contentInstance ==="

def createSensorAndDataInstances():
    while True:
        #generate a random delay
        randomDelay = random.randint(1,5)
        time.sleep(randomDelay)
        createDATAcontentInstance()

createSensorAndDataInstances()
```

If I run  `createSensorAndDataInstances()`, the same simulated temperature is always returned and posted.

My current understanding is that the `random.seed()` method uses the system's current time as the method's parameter and therefore the method should return a random number, which it does, if I run the following code, which is a stripped version of my script code:

```
import random
import time

def randomTemperature():
    random.seed()
    return str(random.randint(25,28))

def createSensorAndDataInstances():
    while True:
        #generate a random delay
        randomDelay = random.randint(1,5)
        time.sleep(randomDelay)
        print randomTemperature()

createSensorAndDataInstances()
```

Does anybody know why it keeps returning the same number in the first case?

**EDIT1:** Tried what @dursk suggested, but it still doesn't work. I made the following changes:

```
create_DATA_contentInstance_xml_body = '''<obj>
                                      <str name="appId" val="''' + new_senzor_name + '''"/>
                                      <str name="category" val="temperature "/>
                                      <int name="data" val="{}"/>
                                      <int name="unit" val="celsius"/>
                                    </obj>
                                    '''
```

And

```
create_DATA_contentInstance = urllib2.Request(url=create_DATA_contentInstance_url , 
                                  data=create_DATA_contentInstance_xml_body.format(randomTemperature()), 
                                  headers={'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='})
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `randomTemperature()` in the xml string excutes *once*, when the module is first loaded. You need to parameterize the string, and call that method, passing a new value every time.

```
create_DATA_contentInstance_xml_body = '''
<obj>
  <str name="appId" val="{}"/>
  <str name="category" val="temperature "/>
  <int name="data" val="{}"/>
  <int name="unit" val="celsius"/>
</obj>
'''

def createDATAcontentInstance():
    urllib2.urlopen(create_DATA_contentInstance.format(
        new_senzor_name,
        randomTemperature()
    )                
    print "\n=== Created a DATA contentInstance ==="
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you're repeatedly calling random.seed() within the same second.
You need to call it ONCE at the beginning of the script and never do it again. It shouldn't be placed in a function you call more than once.

**Sorry**, not really, see durks's answer. But what I said about random.seed() that needs to be called just once per script still stands.

Comment: But how is it called within the same second, if there is a delay between 1 and 5 seconds between every generated temperature value?

Comment: Ever if it were called within the same second, it would still generate a random number as `random.seed()` uses `os.urandom` as its entropy source.